# Kernel Mode Driver and IOCTL

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, ioctl

What I'm trying to do:

1. User-mode app sends Process ID to driver
2. Driver gets handle to specified Process ID
3. Drivers passes opened handle to user-mode app

I'm not sure if this code is even completely working. I'm quite new to drivers, so I haven't set up debugging yet and virtual machine hasn't finished downloading (slow connection problems).

Getting Process ID from user-mode app should be working fine and it should be getting stored in PROCESS_INFO struct as ProcessId. The opened handle is stored in the same struct as ProcessHandle to be sent back to the user-mode application. I'm not sure how to return data from kernel to user-mode tho, maybe someone could explain briefly.

Here's my code:

```
#include <ntifs.h>
#include <wdf.h>

DRIVER_INITIALIZE DriverEntry;

UNICODE_STRING DeviceName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\Device\\GetSysHandle"), SymbolicLink = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\DosDevices\\GetSysHandle");

typedef struct _PROCESS_INFO
{
    HANDLE ProcessId;
    HANDLE ProcessHandle;
}PROCESS_INFO, *PPROCESS_INFO;

BOOLEAN GetSysHandle(PPROCESS_INFO ProcessInfo)
{
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED;
    PEPROCESS eProcess = NULL;

    status = PsLookupProcessByProcessId(ProcessInfo->ProcessId, &eProcess);
    if ((!NT_SUCCESS(status)) || (!eProcess))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    status = ObOpenObjectByPointer(eProcess, 0, NULL, 0, 0, KernelMode, &ProcessInfo->ProcessHandle);

    if ((!NT_SUCCESS(status)) || (!ProcessInfo->ProcessHandle))
    {
        ObDereferenceObject(eProcess);
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

void Unload(PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject)
{
    DbgPrint("# GetSysHandle driver unloaded.");

    IoDeleteSymbolicLink(&SymbolicLink);
    IoDeleteDevice(pDriverObject->DeviceObject);
}

NTSTATUS DriverDispatch(PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, PIRP irp)
{
    PIO_STACK_LOCATION io;
    PPROCESS_INFO ProcessInfo;

    NTSTATUS status;

    io = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation(irp);
    irp->IoStatus.Information = 0;

    switch (io->MajorFunction)
    {
    case IRP_MJ_CREATE:
        status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
        break;
    case IRP_MJ_CLOSE:
        status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
        break;
    case IRP_MJ_READ:
        status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
        break;
    case IRP_MJ_WRITE:

        ProcessInfo = (PPROCESS_INFO)MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe(irp->MdlAddress, NormalPagePriority);

        if (!ProcessInfo)
        {
            status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
            break;
        }

        if (!GetSysHandle(ProcessInfo))
        {
            DbgPrint("# Failed to get process handle");
            status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
            break;
        }

        status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
        irp->IoStatus.Information = sizeof(PROCESS_INFO);

        break;

    default:
        status = STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST;
        break;
    }

    irp->IoStatus.Status = status;

    IoCompleteRequest(irp, IO_NO_INCREMENT);
    return status;
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT  DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject;
    ULONG i;

    DbgPrint("# GetSysHandle driver loaded");

    IoCreateDevice(DriverObject, 0, &DeviceName, FILE_DEVICE_UNKNOWN, FILE_DEVICE_SECURE_OPEN, FALSE, &DeviceObject);
    IoCreateSymbolicLink(&SymbolicLink, &DeviceName);

    for (i = 0;i<IRP_MJ_MAXIMUM_FUNCTION;i++)
    {
        DriverObject->MajorFunction[i] = DriverDispatch;
    }

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: If this is linux, you might want to say so (and use the linux-kernel tag). If it's not linux, you definitely need to say what OS this driver will run on

Comment: @ArlieStephens: this is clearly not linux.

Comment: @MarkJensen: only guessed linux because it's the one I most often see referred to as "The kernel", as if it were the only kernel in existence.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost (to avoid confusion): this code is for Windows and Windows Drivers.

The biggest issue I see with your driver code is that you aren't registering the IRP major functions inside of DriverEntry. You will need to set the `MajorFunction` parameters of the `PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject` to the dispatch functions. Without assigning these `MajorFunctions`, the driver will have no way of knowing what function to call when receiving a command.

To do this, break up the cases for the `switch (io->MajorFunction)` into different dispatch functions. For example, `IRP_MJ_WRITE` will be its own function, and you can declare it like so:

```
DRIVER_DISPATCH DispatchReadFunction;
```

In this case, we will want all read commands issued to the driver to run whatever code is inside the `DispatchReadFunction` function. So the definition will look a little like this:

```
NTSTATUS DispatchReadFunction(_In_ PDEVICE_OBJECT DriverObject, _In_ PIRP Irp)
{
     NTSTATUS status = STATUS_SUCCESS;
     //Do read code here
     return status;
}
```

Once we have the `DispatchReadFunction` function written, you will need to assign it to the `DriverObject->MajorFunction` in the `DriverEntry` function like so:

`DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_READ] = DispatchReadFunction;`

Finally, stub out and write the rest of the `IRP_MJ_` functions that you need, making sure that you assign them to the `MajorFunction` memeber of `DriverObject`.

My `DriverEntry` function looks like this (I removed extra functionality):

```
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
     NTSTATUS status;
     status = STATUS_SUCCESS;

     DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_READ]           = DispatchReadFunc;
     DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CREATE]         = DispatchCreateFunc;
     DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_CLOSE]          = DispatchCloseFunc;
     DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_WRITE]          = DispatchWriteFunc;
     DriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_DEVICE_CONTROL] = DispatchDevCtrlFunc;

     return status;
}
```

A good starting point would be [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8744/Exchange-data-between-device-drivers-and-user-appl). This link also includes a simple example (driver code and application code) that does what you are attempting to do.

Good Luck!